# Closest Point on a Line in SQL Server Spatial 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, geometry, spatial, spatial-query

In an ideal world I would be running on SQL Server 2012 and be able to use the .ShortestLineTo() function to find the closest point on a line, to that of another point.  I currently am able to find the closest line to my point - but now I need to find the coordinates of the point closest to my point in question.

Unfortunately I am stuck on SQL Server 2008 R2, so don't have the option to use .ShortestLineTo().

How do others achieve this in SQL Server Spatial Geometry types?

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but if it still helps (or for anyone else) you should be able to do the following with SQL 2008.

```
DECLARE @point GEOMETRY = GEOMETRY::STPointFromText('POINT(0 0)', 0);
DECLARE @line GEOMETRY = GEOMETRY::STLineFromText('POINT(10 10, 20 20)', 0);

SELECT STIntersection(@point.STBuffer(@point.STDistance(@line)));
```

Essentially, you calculate the distance between the two geometries,use that as a buffer on the point which should result in the geometries touching, and take the intersection (point) of that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... my lines have multiple sets of points.

Answer (score 0):

**Note @Road is the same as geography MULTILINESTRING**

**SET INITIAL ROAD SEGMENT**
*SET @Road* = geography::STMLineFromText('MULTILINESTRING ((-79.907603999999992 32.851905999999985, -79.907708999999983 32.851751, -79.907879999999992 32.851555999999995, -79.907889999999981 32.851542999999992, -79.907995999999983 32.851461, -79.90813399999999 32.851373999999986, -79.90833499999998 32.851286999999992, -79.908529 32.85121, -79.909110999999982 32.850974))', 4269);

**GET START/END POINTS OF ROAD SEGMENT FOR NEW MIDPOINT CALCULATION**
*SET @x1* = CAST(@Road.STStartPoint().Lat   AS decimal(11,6))
*SET @y1* = CAST(@Road.STStartPoint().Long  AS decimal(12,6))
*SET @x2* = CAST(@Road.STEndPoint().Lat     AS decimal(11,6))
*SET @y2* = CAST(@Road.STEndPoint().Long    AS decimal(12,6))

**ASSIGN ROAD SEGMENT MIDPOINT LAT/LON**
*SET @MidPointLat* = CAST( ((@x1 + @x2) / 2) AS nvarchar(11))
*SET @MidPointLon* = CAST( ((@y1 + @y2) / 2) AS nvarchar(12))

**SET INITIAL OFF ROAD CENTROID**
*SET @RoadMidPt*        = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + @MidPointLon + ' ' + @MidPointLat + ')', 4269)

**CALCULATE BUFFER DISTANCE BACK TO ROAD FOR .STIntersection** (add .02 to ensure intersect)
*SET @RoadMidPtBuffer*  = @RoadMidPt.STBuffer(@RoadMidPt.STDistance(@Road) + .02)

**Might intersect at multiple points! Use 1st point that intersects road as centroid**
*SET @RoadCentroid*     = @RoadMidPtBuffer.STIntersection(@Road).STPointN(1);

**FINAL NEW LAT/LON OF CLOSEST ROAD/LINE CENTROID**
SELECT @RoadCentroid.Lat, @RoadCentroid.Long